# Data from Realtime Firebase is displaying in console but not in html page

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

Component.ts

plats is the root node of my Firebase database,I want to display every child of my root node in 
angular page.The data is displayed in console but not in angular page. Thank you for your helps in 
advance.

```
    itemValue = '';
    name: string;
    plats: Observable<any[]>;
    itemRef: AngularFireObject<any>;

    constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) 
    {
    this.itemRef = db.object('plats');
    this.itemRef.snapshotChanges().subscribe(action => {
    const data = action.payload.val();
    console.log(action.payload.val());
    return { ...data };
    });

 }
```

component.html

```
    <div class="container">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Community</th>
        </tr>
       <tr *ngFor="let item of plats | async">
          <td>{{item}}</td>  
      </tr> 
     </table>
   </div>
```

Comment: plats is null..

Comment: It contains data i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of plats">
  <td>{{item}}</td>  
</tr>
```

in your code here you want to access the value of key element. just access it like {{item.key}}. hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Assign data to `plats`

.ts

```
const data = action.payload.val();
this.plats = data;
```

template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of plats">
  <td>{{item}}</td>  
</tr>
```

OR

Keep your *.ts* file as it is and in template, use `itemRef`

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of itemRef | async">
   <td>{{item}}</td>  
</tr>
```

Comment: It throws error as Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: Remove `| async` from template

Comment: @AdritaSharma I think `itemRef` with async will not work as its type is SnapshotChange?

Comment: same error again mam and when i remove async then it generates "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Comment: The first way should have worked. I am not sure, Can you share it in stackbiltz

Comment: @Sourav Can you just console the value of `data` I mean - `console.log(data)` What it gives you? Is there any error in the console?

Comment: What do you mean by `it works same`? Can you show the screenshot of console.log?

Comment: @AdritaSharma In stackbiltz i cant show the firebase initialization apikey and token.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.itemRef = db.object('plats');
this.plats = this.itemRef.snapshotChanges().map(items => {
  return items.map(val => {
    const data = val.payload.doc.data();
    const id = val.payload.doc.id;
    return { id, ...data };
});
```

Comment: I tried this before but i got some error as "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<SnapshotAction<any>>"..... Inspite i have imported the map from 'rxjs/operators'

Comment: Do i have to include pipe ?

Comment: @Sourav Checked your screenshot, its Object with key value pair. What do you want to access from that Objects? `bigfork` key's object? or what?

Comment: i need to access the whole object like bigfork , cdl ,crc etc. I just want to show the data which is inside my root node.

Comment: i don't want to access the value of a particular key, i want to access the whole object

Comment: @Sourav n what about halfmoon key ? Why it's different from other obj?

Comment: I Created that for button. It contains Key value pairs in form of array.

Comment: Lets forget about halfmoon, if i want to access objects with same keys. Then what should be the approach

Comment: @Sourav search for object.keys

Comment: how to do this, i didn't get it ?